# How does `useTracker` know what to subscribe to?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-hooks

Going through the [Meteor basic tutorial](https://react-tutorial.meteor.com/simple-todos/02-collections.html#2-3-Render-Tasks-Collection), I am having some issues getting the "task list" to update automatically when I insert an item, so wanted to debug it.

The main app component uses the `useTracker` function hook to "subscribe" to changes in the TasksCollection:

```
const tasks = useTracker(() => TasksCollection.find({}).fetch());

return (
  <div>
    <ul>{ tasks.map(task => <Task key={ task._id } task={ task }/>) }</ul>
  </div>
);
```

I am having a really hard time understanding how `useTracker` works under the hood.

Isn't the result of `fetch()` a plain array? How does `useTracker` know that it needs to subscribe to anything? I doubt that it polls the collection randomly.

I am not sure if this is even related to Meteor, or is it just some React Hooks magic.

Comment: Your question seems to be around react hooks.  In this case, useTracker returns an object "tasks".  You get a re-render in your component when tasks change.  Its very likely that useTracker has state in it that once is set causes that component to re-render, which then breaks object equality to the "tasks" object, which causes your component to re-render

Comment: @terpinmd: but `.fetch()` returns an array of tasks (actually a `Mongo.Document[]` array. When I update the `TaskCollection`, meteor syncs it with the server and then somehow causes this function to be invoked again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually wrong. `useTracker` doesn't subscribe to anything. You are responsible for subscribing yourself. The only thing `useTracker` does is connect updates to your collections (a "reactive data-source" in Meteor nomenclature) to a reactive event in react (similar to `useState`).

Check your code for a call to `Meteor.subscribe('tasks')` (or similar).

Comment: Meteor has `minimongo` on the client (browser), when you call `Meteor.subscribe` function, it will sync documents from Mongodb on the server to the `minimongo` on the client.
`useTracker` you're calling on the client "watches" changes on `minimongo` then reflects that changes in react reactive variable.

Comment: @Christian I don't have `subscribe` anywhere in the code explicitly, but when I update the `TaskCollection`, it also triggers the update of the hook. But the issue is that I basically have `const tasks = useTracker(() => new [])`, the result of the function call is an array of `Document`, which is not reactive. I don't know how `Meteor.subscribe('tasks')` would tell React "hey, you need to update that `useTracker` which mentions `TaskCollection` in the method body". So I am presuming that it just refreshes all `useTracker` instances whenever there is a change in any of the collections.

Comment: Ok I just confirmed this, when any collection in the minimongo store is updated, *all* `useTracker` hooks get called again, after which React checks which of the results were changed. I confirmed by adding another `useTracker` for a different collection and adding logging to the body of the function provided to `useTracker`. When I updated the `TaskCollection`, both hook functions were called. Thanks!